# xamarin.forms notification tap and navigation from app.xaml.cs

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a xamarin.forms app in which I am using **Plugin.LocalNotification** [Link](https://github.com/thudugala/Plugin.LocalNotification) to make local push notifications in android and ios.Notifications works fine. The problem is I want to open one of my shared screen when tapping on the notification in android and ios.I done the click according to the documentation lie this.

**In my App.xamal.cs**

```
    public App()
            {
                InitializeComponent();

 Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LandingPage());
                NotificationCenter.Current.NotificationTapped += OnLocalNotificationTapped;                  
            }

            private void OnLocalNotificationTapped(NotificationTappedEventArgs e)

            {          

                        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new SECLandingScreen(Isnotification));
                        ((NavigationPage)MainPage).BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#19110F");
                        ((NavigationPage)MainPage).BarTextColor = Color.Snow;               
                }
            }
```

**My problem**

I can navigate to the notification screen when notification tapped. But I can't navigate to previous screen by pressing back button.How should be the navigation for making click the notification from any screen and navigate to previous screen on backpress?

Comment: instead of assigning a new value to MainPage (which removes any previous navigation) you need to get a reference to the current navigation stack and push a new page onto it

Comment: @Jason can you give me some snippet?

Comment: check to see if MainPage is already an instance of NavigationPage, if so use it to PushAsync a new page

Comment: @Jason for normal navigation when starts, I use  Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LandingPage());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if MainPage is already an instance of NavigationPage, if so use it to PushAsync a new page

```
var nav = (NavigationPage)MainPage;

if (nav != null) 
{
  nav.PushAsync(new SECLandingScreen(Isnotification));
}
```